# SQL Query to find missing records between two tables and then update the second with the missing records from the first

Tags: mysql

Two tables. 8 fields in each. Both tables have the same data, one with 
137,002 record (tablea) and one with 135,759 records (tableb). Both tables share a common primary field if three columns (qid, sid, aid).

Is there a single query that will.
1) compare tablea to tableb on the primary field
and
2) if the record is in tablea and not tableb copy the record from tablea to tableb

I would rather be able to update tableb with an sql query rather than writing a php loop to go through the 137,002 and do a compare on each one.

Thanks

Comment: Both tables have the same data: 137002 <> 135759.

Comment: We had a crash of the table [tableb]. I truncated it, restored from a backup, and it didn't restore all the records. I was unaware of it. The application added more records to the old table [tableb] before we were aware that there were missing records. I then created a new table [tablea], restored the backup that did restore all the records. Now I want to merge the unrestored records [tablea] from the second (new) table to the first (old) table so that the old table [tableb] is complete. So, for the most part the data is duplicated in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

That should be smth looking like:

```
insert into table2 (qid, sid ...)
    select  
        t1.qid,
        t1.sid,
        ...
    from table1 t1
    where 
        not exist (select t2.qid, t2.sid, ... from table2 t2 where t2.qid = t1.qid and t2.sid = t1.sid...)
```

Comment: The primary is made up from three fields `qid`, `sid` and `aid` using this query will falsify the first table if there are double `qid`'s

Comment: @stUrb It's just an example, showing the way to go. But anyway i've updated `where` clause to match you preferences better

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge`...and use `insert` only....not `update`.

Comment: does mysql have a `merge` clause?

Comment: @Sergio it doesn't. But you can use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... as replacement. Although i love your solution with a subquery.

Comment: @karelG not sure but seems `insert on duplicate key update` will have killing performance, but hope it's optimized like ms sql `merge`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tableb AS b
(SELECT * FROM tablea AS a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableb AS b2 WHERE b2.id = a.id))
```

Comment: @Sergio, I noticed that you edited this answer. In terms of performance, will this answer be better than your initial one above or is the performance about the same?

Answer (score 0):

So, the following worked.

```
insert into f_step_ans (`qid`, `assid`, `sid`, `sas`, `cas`, `etim`, `stim`, `endtim`, `fil`)
select  
    t1.qid,
    t1.assid,
    t1.sid,
    t1.sas,
    t1.cas,
    t1.etim,
    t1.stim,
    t1.endtim,
    t1.fil
from f_step_ans_back t1
where 
    not exists (select t2.qid, t2.sid,t2.assid from f_step_ans as t2 where t2.qid = t1.qid and t2.assid = t1.assid and t2.sid = t1.sid)
```

1,588 records were moved from the `f_step_ans_back` table (old backup table) to the `f_step_ans` table (partially recovered backup + new data). Reporting shows that everything is working like it should be. Thank you all for the help.